# Size of black hole

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

I am wondering about size of [black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole). How is it possible that we have black holes of different sizes? As I know the singularity is point which is infinite small and is infinite dense. So my question is how can infinite dense and infinite small object create different size black holes. We have different big infinite singularities?

Comment: Usually when we talk about the size of the black hole we're talking about its event horizon.  You're right it doesn't make much sense to talk about the size of the singularity.  Plus, due to the extremely distorted space I'm pretty sure you can measure an arbitrarily long length inside of the black hole that's arbitrarily small outside of it.  That is, I'm pretty sure the curvature allows a black hole to be "much bigger" inside than it is outside.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: I think you might want to make that a separate question and spell out in more detail what you have in mind.

Comment: Nobody has ever seen an infinitely small and infinitely dense object. This is an example of an over-extrapolation of a theory that makes absolutely no statements about the microscopic states of dense matter. It doesn't predict the density of planets, stars or even neutron stars all by itself. We always have to add an equation of state the regulates the density as a function of pressure (and temperature) to general relativity to make these predictions. We simply do not have an equation of state for the interiors of black holes.

Answer (score 2):

A black hole has two main features:

1. a singularity
2. an event horizon

The event horizon is a sphere with a certain radius. Most people visualize the singularity as a point at the center of the sphere, and although that's not quite rigorously right, it's good enough for the purposes of the present discussion.

Using a rough Newtonian analogy, the event horizon is like the surface from which the escape velocity exceeds the speed of light. In the real relativistic theory, it's boundary that no cause-and-effect relationships can cross from the inside out.

Black holes form by the gravitational collapse of massive bodies. You can think of the singularity as the place where all the in-falling matter accumulated.

When people talk about the radius of a black hole, they usually mean the radius of the event horizon.

> Thank you, but what is making that diference between sizes of event horizons (we have got super massive black holes, smaller blackholes? I mean how is possible that one blackhole is smaller than the other or bigger when singularity is just infinite in size and mass ?

Different black holes have singularities containing different amounts of mass. The mass is not infinite. For example, if a star with a mass of 6 solar masses collapses to form a black hole, then the black hole is a 6-solar-mass black hole. The size of the event horizon is proportional to the mass.

Comment: Thank you, but what is making that diference between sizes of event horizons (we have got super massive black holes, smaller blackholes? I mean how is possible that one blackhole is smaller than the other or bigger when singularity is just infinite in size and mass ? When is once something infinite small and infinite dense why it doesn´t create still same big black hole ? why is that event horizon still different in size ? Or singularity is  that point in the middle and around him there is another mass which is creating size of black hole  ? Sorry for english.

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome back :-)  I made a comment above on the question suggesting the curvature inside of the black hole does strange things with "length".  Am I completely off?  Can you say more about what reference frame the radius is measured in?

Comment: @TomasKlema: I edited the answer to respond to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how can infinite dense and infinite small object
>   create different size black holes.

The singularity within a black hole is not the crucial consideration here.

If an amount of (non-spinning, non-charged) mass $M$ is contained within a volume of radius of $r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$, the mass $M$ is 'hidden' within a spherical [event horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Event_horizon_of_a_black_hole) (black hole) of radius $r_s$.

Thus, the larger the mass $M$, the larger the radius $r_s$ of the black hole.

The result that the mass cannot remain static within the horizon and must collapse to a singularity is secondary to the above result.

Answer (score 0):

Different black holes have different masses. For non-rotating black holes, the distance
$$r=\frac{2Gm}{c^2}$$
describes the event horizon. As you can see, the mass $m$ of the black hole enters here. [This WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius) on the Schwarzschild radius describes has more information.

Answer (score 0):

Different sizes are formed because while infinitely small there is technically a measurable amount of mass. That mass creates a different size event horizon like event horizon is gravitational pull no return point. Like he said a 6 solar mass star becomes a black hole it will have X as its event horizon now lets say it collides with a 10 mass black hole. It will now be a 16 mass black hole whos event horizon size will now be X1+X2. The size of the black hole is dictated by first how large of a star created it PLUS whatever it collides with after

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).